# Issue with output while using python and jinja2 to generate grafana json panels for dashboards

Tags: json, python-3.x, string, jinja2

I am working on some code to generate dashboard json files specific for Solarwinds.

I need to generate a set of panels to monitor all critical links in the solarwinds.
The issue I am facing is in the Grafana Text Panel that should present the description of each link. There are no queries, I am suing a csv file a generated with all the links relevant information.

**Python code to load the csv file**

```
# Python source to read csv fileSource csv file
## load list with csv data
with open('crit_links.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader)
```

**Sample line of the csv file**

**crilinks.csv sample**

```
businesshq;17;SWLINKS-bus;121;Unit: 1 Slot: 0 Port: 2 Gbit - Level · L2L_HLD-area_comp;111.111.111.110;103;OSPF;FALSE;02/03/20 05:19;;;;
```

**Python code that generates the panels list for the dashboard**

```
grid_Xa = [0,6,8,10]
grid_Xb = [12,18,20,22]
for i, row in enumerate(data):
    rowlist = str(row).split(';')
    if i == 0: 
        titlerow = rowlist #row of titles froms list columns dos items da lista
        grid_y = initial_y
        continue

    if i % 2 == 1:
        for x in grid_Xa:
            if x == 0:
                panelsList.append(createTextPanel(rowlist[0],rowlist[2],rowlist[4],x,grid_y, i+1))
                continue
```

**createTextPanel python function**

```
def createTextPanel(siteName,nodeName,interfaceName,grid_X,grid_Y,g_id):
    template = jenv.get_or_select_template('p-text.json.jinja') 
    return template.render( site=siteName, node=nodeName,interface=interfaceName ,grid_x = grid_X, grid_y = grid_Y,id=g_id)
```

**jinja template:**

```
{
  "content": "Site: " + {{site}} + "Node: " +  {{node}} + "Interface: " + {{interface}},
  "gridPos": {
    "h": 3,
    "w": 6,
    "x": {{ grid_x }},
    "y": {{ grid_y }}
  },...}
```

**Problem:**

The {{site}} string in the output.json is appearing with **['** and this is crashing the quotes

**output json:**

```
{
  "content": "Site: " + ['businessh1 + "Node: " +  SWLINKS-bus + "Interface: " + Unit: 1 Slot: 0 Port: 2 Gbit - Level · L2L_HLD-area_comp,
  "gridPos": {
    "h": 3,
    "w": 6,
    "x": 0,
    "y": 3
  },
  ...}
```

My intention was that the content: parameter of the output look like this:

```
"output": "Site: businessh1 Node: SWLINKS-bus Interface: Unit: 1 Slot: 0 Port: 2 Gbit - Level · L2L_HLD-area_comp..."
```

*Thanks!*

Comment: Also tried with the jinja template like this:
'''{
  "content": "Site: {{site}}  Node: {{node}}  Interface: {{interface}}",
  "gridPos": {
    "h": 3,
    "w": 6,
    "x": {{ grid_x }},
    "y": {{ grid_y }}
  },'''
The output presented the same issue:
"content": "Site:  **['businessh1** ..."

Comment: Also tried using a comma separated csv file instead of semi-colon as separator.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue changing the following:

From:

```
# Python source to read csv fileSource csv file
## load list with csv data
with open('crit_links.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader)
```

To:

```
# load list with csv data
with open('crit_links.csv') as f:
data = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=','))
```